# Treeview and Scrollbar interaction using excel vba 2003

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, treeview, scrollbar

Currently i working on a project on a excel dashboard using excel 2003

I have this custom class created and have a collection of this classes.

```
Dim classCollection as Collection
```

The skeletal structure of the custom class say CustomClass1 is as shown

```
Dim objName as string
Dim subClass as Collection

Public Sub CreateSubClass()

Dim cClass as CustomClass1

'manipulation and stuff goes here

subClass.Add cClass

end Sub
```

As you can see, there is also a sub collection of its own class as i would like to do a further breakdown with more attributes and stuff of the class module

Previously i am able to display the collection into the cells without any sub collection with scrollbar which also controls the index of the collection as shown below(sorry for the crude drawing, that's the best i could to depict as i cannot post pictures)

```
   ^ obj20
   l obj21
   l obj22
   l obj23
   v obj24
```

The scrollbar change coding is as below

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim classObject As CustomClass1
If classCollection.Count = 0 Then
    Call initialise_dataset
End If
    ScrollBar1.Min = 0
    ScrollBar1.Max = classCollection.Count - 7
    If ScrollBar1.Value < (classCollection.Count - 7) Then
    For i = 0 To 6
    Set classObject = classCollection(i + ScrollBar1.Value + 1)
        Cells(5 + i, 2).Value = classObject.objName

Next i
End If

If ScrollBar1.Value > 0 Then
If classCollection.Count = 0 Then
    Call initialise_dataset
End If
For i = 0 To 6
Set classObject = classCollection(i + ScrollBar1.Value + 1)
    Cells(5 + i, 2).Value = classObject.objName

Next i
End If
Debug.Print ScrollBar1.Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So right now i will like add in the treeview to display sub classes as well. But the scrollbar value will be affected with the treeview function which also will not allow me to get the actual index of the collection. So is there any workarounds that i can do to make the treeview work along with the scrollbar.

A rough idea is like this

```
^ -obj20
l   obj20_1 
l   obj20_2
l +obj21
v +obj22
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. As for the + and - signs, i can use a followthrough hyperlink to tag the class object. So there will be no issues on that.